# Are there always continuous extensions to closures

Tags: general-topology

Given a map $X,Y \in Top$ where $Y$ is Hausdorff and a map $f:A \rightarrow Y$ is there always a unique extension  $\bar{f}:\bar{A} \rightarrow Y$ to the closure?

Say by, letting $x_i \rightarrow x \in (\bar{A}-A)$ be a net, and defining $\bar{f}x:=lim(fx_i)$?

It doesn't appear not as per the answer below, the problem appears to have enough limits in $Y$ - is there a natural condition that allows this - completion appears to be neccessary but not sufficient, but that also means $Y$ needs to be uniformisable.

Answer (score 3):

No. Let $A, Y$ be the open unit disc in $\mathbb R^2$ and $f:A \to Y$ be the identity. $\overline A$ is compact, so any extension would be onto (in our case), which is impossible as $Y$ is not compact.

(and in your case, $\lim(fx_i)$ might not exist).

For another example, let $A = (0,+\infty) \subset \mathbb R$ and $Y=\mathbb R$, then $f(x)=1/x$ cannot be extended to $[0,+\infty)$.

Comment: Making $Y$ complete clears your first example, but not the second. The problem appears to be having enough limits in $Y$ for the construction to work.

Comment: It also has something to do with the function itself: for example if $f$ is Lipschitz (for example if all the spaces are metric spaces), then there can be an extension $\bar f :\bar A \to \bar Y$.